# How is DBMS or RDBMS related to MS SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

I've just started learning some stuffs about DB, and I've realized there are DBMS and RDBMS.

I personally use MS SQL SERVER 2014 and MS SQL Server Management Studio 2014. How can I determine / choose if I want to use a `DBMS` or `RDBMS`, how am I related to that, how can I know what I'm working with?

If someone asks me "Are you using rdbms or dbms" what should I answer?

Does my system becoming RDBMS if I relate tables together or what?

I don't understand this.

Comment: This is not an important distinction.  Answer:  "SQL Server".

Comment: I don't think anyone is ever going to ask you that question. The R stands for relational and I don't think any of the non-relational things would ever call themselves a DBMS. RDBMS is describing the platform, not what you're doing with it. SQL Server is an RDBMS - it doesn't matter if you use foreign keys, it doesn't matter if you think about it in terms of relational tables, it doesn't matter if you use Management Studio. A Chevy Silverado is a pickup truck. It doesn't matter if I use it to pick things up or if I ever use the back to "truck" anything. It's still a truck.

Comment: @GordonLinoff May you share your knowledge with beginners here, and answer my questions in a post above? there are 3 questions, could you answer it one by one so me and probably many people more could clear this .. Thanks Gordon

Comment: https://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2015/08/relational-databases-vs-non-relational-databases/ - please let me know if in your reading or searching you ever across someone using the term "DBMS" as an explicit and intentional distinction from "RDBMS" - I don't travel in all the circles but I have yet to hear that.

Comment: Typically people ask you "_which_ DBMS are you using" - they usually don't ask "are you using a RDBMS?". With that question they ask which the database _product_ you are using. In your case the answer is "Microsoft SQL Server". They ask this question because a solution that works with the database product "Microsoft SQL Server" might very different to a solution that works with the database product "PostgreSQL".

Answer (score 2):

DBMS ( database management system) the R in RDBMS stands for "Relational" , relational databases have certain rules to be followed called "normal forms", these forms preserve the integrity and facilitate data management by reducing redundancy. The first 4 normal forms are important  , there is more forms but they are more of an academic interest only.
As for MS sql server, it is an RDBMS because it follows the relational structure. Same for mysql and even oracle ( there is an object oriented approach for Oracle)
RDBMS's are widely used because they always proved to be reliable owing to the fact that they are based on algebra.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have asked about the difference between DBMS and MS SQL Server Management Studio, I thought I would explain about it a bit.

A database management system (DBMS) is a program used to create, update, and manage databases. RDBMS means a relational database management system, and it helps to create, update and manage relational databases. One of such RDBMS is Microsoft SQL server.

MS SQL Server Management Studio is a software which provides graphical interface to manage the underlying RDBMS, MS SQL Server. If you want to see what the databases in your MS SQL Server are, looking at those through MS SQL Server Management Studio is more visually comfortable and appealing. Furthermore, MS SQL Server Management Studio makes the administrative and troubleshooting activities of the databases easier.

You can read more about MS SQL Server Management Studio [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16)